# blinking an led using timer interrupt (atmega 128)

Tags: c, timer, atmel

I'm trying to blink an led without using the delay function.
I came across using the timer interrupt and I tried it, and it compiles fine. But the output is fixed on PORTA = 0x01; so, I believe the ISR function is not working. Is there anything I am missing in the code? Thanks.

```
#include <asf.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

volatile unsigned int count=0;
volatile unsigned int tTime=0;

void port_init(void) {
    PORTA = 0xff;
}

ISR(TIMER0_OVF_vect)
{
    TCNT0 = 206;
    count++;
    if (count < 625) {
        PORTA=0x01;
    }
    else if ((count > 625) && (count < 1250)) {
        PORTA=0x00;
    }
    else {
        count=0;
    }
}

int main (void)
{ 
    board_init();
    port_init();

    TCCR0 = 0x06; //setting dispensing ratio
    TCNT0 = 206; //initial value of register
    TIMSK = 0x01; //enabling interrupt
    SREG=0x80;

    DDRA=0xff;
    while(1){
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by the "program doesn't seem to work"? Can you please elaborate? Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/

Comment: Sorry about that. It's my first time asking a question in this site! The problem is that the program is compiling without any errors, but the led does not blink. I believe it is fixed on PORTA=0x01; and the ISR function is not working. Is there a problem in my coding?

Comment: @NicholasLee there is a problem with your debugging.  Use your JTAG, or whatever, debug interface to put a breakpoint on the interrupt handler.  If you do not have a debug interface, get one.  You wil need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a logic error in your `ISR()` function.  Once `count` hits 625 the first two `if/else-if` clauses will be `false` (because 625 is neither less than, nor greater than, 625), thus the final `else` clause will execute and reset `count` to zero.  The result of this is that the else-if clause that sets PORTA=0x00 will never execute.

To fix, change the first `if` from `<` to `<=`, like so:

```
if (count <= 625) {
```

Comment: thank you so much. I fixed it like you suggested and it worked immediately.

Comment: Excellent!  Please take a minute to select my answer as the correct answer to your question.